# How to solve a quadratic equation in R?

Tags: r

I need to solve this but I definitely have no clue. I know it’s something very basic but I don’t get it : ax2 + bx + c = 0

```
a <- 1

b <- -8

c <- 12

d <- b*b-4*a*c
```

Thank you.

Comment: b^2 - (4*a*c) ?

Comment: d <- b*b-4*a*c  . I don’t know why it doesn’t show up the * mark between the first two “b”: b*b

Comment: What is the difficulty you encounter? You want to solve it manually or you're looking for a R function which solves polynomial equations?

Comment: Yes, I need to perform it in R.

Answer (score 8):

The following is an implementation of the quadratic formula,

[image]

which will give the roots of ax^2 + bx + c = 0. If the roots are complex, it will return the complex values. If both roots are the same, it will return a single value:

```r
quad <- function(a, b, c)
{
  a <- as.complex(a)
  answer <- c((-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a),
              (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a))
  if(all(Im(answer) == 0)) answer <- Re(answer)
  if(answer[1] == answer[2]) return(answer[1])
  answer
}
```

So in your case, we would have:

```r
quad(a = 1, b = -8, c = 12)
#> [1] 6 2
```

So, we know that x^2 -8 *x + 12 = 0 when x is 2 or 6. This is straightforward to verify by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming if you have to come up with two solutions for x^2 - 8x + 12 = 0 based on your perimeters stored as variables a, b, & c :

a <- 1

b <- -8

c <- 12

You would type out the two quadratic equations in R and come up with the two solutions:

(-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c) ) / ( 2*a )

*Solution 1 => 6*

(-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c) ) / ( 2*a )

*Solution 2 => 2*

- Note the asterisks between 4ac in the equation doesn't not show up in this post but needs to be placed in R